# Can I switch html5mode off for development in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, html5-history

I have an AngularJS project using html5mode with multiple developers working on it from different backgrounds. (This is a community project).

I'm having issues where different developers run different servers and are often unsure of how to set up rewriting (all requests to index.html in order for html5mode to work). My setup is WAMP and so included in the project is a .htaccess file but not everyone uses Apache.

Is there a way to temporarily disable html5mode without then having to manually change all links in Angular to use '#/...' in routes and the like? Thus removing the need for server config.